# What tabletop setting (if any) is this 1980s map from?

Tags: product-identification, campaign-settings, maps

My dad found a photo from his college D&D game, and we're wondering what setting this map on the wall might be from.
[image: A group of four people sit around a table playing Dungeons and Dragons. A large map hangs on the wall behind the group.]
The photo was taken in 1986, and my dad doesn't recall any specific setting information about the game (or, honestly, much information at all, aside from the fact that paladins were killjoys back in the day.). His DM was an author who wrote a couple of Conan novels, but he unfortunately passed away quite some time ago, so we can't exactly ask him personally.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

That is a map of Middle-Earth showing the south and east along with the traditional map section from the novels.

[image: Map of Middle-earth – a higher-quality image of the map photographed in the question]

As noted in [the listing for this Middle-earth map on Geographicus.com](https://www.geographicus.com/P/AntiqueMap/middleearth-fenlon-1982-2), this map was illustrated by Pete Fenlon, co-founder of Iron Crown Enterprises. Titled *An Artist's Interpretation of Middle Earth Including the Wild Lands - East, South & North*, the map was first printed in 1982 as part of the *Middle-earth Role-Playing* (*MERP*) supplement *A Campaign and Adventure Guidebook for Middle-earth*. Many parts of the map were seemingly not based on Tolkien's writings, but rather invented by Fenlon.

Comment: Doy. You'd think one of our family members would've recognized it! Thanks for the link to the full image, though, that's neat!

Comment: Specifically it was a map made by Iron Crown Enterprises for their Middle-Earth Roleplaying system.  They made up the southern and eastern lands there, doesn’t come from Tolkien.  Most of the map is only accurate when playing in that game system.

Comment: @suchiuomizu information is worth including in the answer. Can you edit it and add that?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include some of the details mentioned in the comments and in the page your answer already included a link to. Please look over the post ot amke sure I've maintained your intent.

Comment: did you check MERP Assistant on google play ? It's an app to help you with tables.